# Searching for key in a dictionary, when the key is an object. C#

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

```
//Checking if there already exists a relationship
if (tree.ContainsKey(parent))
{
    `//get the current children
    temp = tree[parent];

    //add the new child
    temp = temp.Append(child).ToArray();

    //overwrite the current children
    tree[parent] = temp;


    //create new record with null children
    tree[child] = new Node[] { };`
}
```

The above code describes the process of checking if there already exists a key(parent) in he dictionary(tree). In this case the key is an object.

While debugging I noticed that it does not detected keys which already exist, yet I do not know the reason.

Below find attached two images - an image of the key which is already in the dictionary, an image of the key which is being checked.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the type in question override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`?  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @David no it does not override the Equals and GetHashCode methods. I hope the code below helps https://codeshare.io/wnW7X9

Comment: Relevant code should be included in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [a comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74309061/searching-for-key-in-a-dictionary-when-the-key-is-an-object-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment131189481_74309061):

> it does not override the Equals and GetHashCode methods

Then this assertion is false:

> keys which already exist

Two objects are not the same just because their properties have the same values.  Much in the same way that two people are not the same person just because they have the same name.

In the absence of any logic indicating otherwise, the *default* comparison for "sameness" for objects is *reference equality*.  So unless the two references point to the same object in memory, they are not the same object.

You can provide custom comparison logic by overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in your class.  The `Dictionary<>` would then be able to use your logic to determine if two objects are "the same".

In this *specific* case I think maybe `GetHashCode` is the only one that's *required* of the two, but it's always a good idea to override both any time you want to implement "sameness".  You might also implement `IComparable`, override `ToString`, etc.

---

A quick example to demonstrate, this should write the first `Count` to the console but throw an exception for the second `Dictionary<>` saying:

> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // adds a second record
        var notSameDict = new Dictionary<NotSame, int>();
        notSameDict.Add(new NotSame { Foo = "test" }, 1);
        notSameDict.Add(new NotSame { Foo = "test" }, 2);
        Console.WriteLine(notSameDict.Count);
        
        // does not add a second record
        var sameDict = new Dictionary<Same, int>();
        sameDict.Add(new Same { Foo = "test" }, 1);
        sameDict.Add(new Same { Foo = "test" }, 2);
        Console.WriteLine(sameDict.Count);
    }
}

public class NotSame
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

public class Same
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Foo.Equals((obj as Same).Foo);   
    }
    
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Foo.GetHashCode();   
    }
}
```